# Why apply() is no faster than commit() in SharedPreferences.Editor

Tags: android

I just learned the difference between apply() and commit() of SharedPreferences.Editor. apply() is said to be asynchronous and is safe to run on UI thread; commit() is said to be synchronous and not suitable to run on UI thread. So I did a simple test with a click listener in MainActivity:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = MainActivity.this.getSharedPreferences("synced", 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
for (int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i) {
    editor.putString("index" + i, "index" + i);
}
Log.e("Test", System.nanoTime() + " SYNC ");
editor.commit();
Log.e("Test", System.nanoTime() + " SYNC " + sharedPreferences.getString("index99999", "NULL"));

SharedPreferences sharedPreferences2 = MainActivity.this.getSharedPreferences("asynced", 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor2 = sharedPreferences2.edit();
for (int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i) {
    editor2.putString("index2" + i, "index2" + i);
}
Log.e("Test", System.nanoTime() + " ASYNC ");
editor2.apply();
Log.e("Test", System.nanoTime() + " ASYNC " + sharedPreferences2.getString("index299999", "NULL"));
```

I run it several time and received the same result like this:

```
05-25 01:11:44.608 16109-16109/darklord.preferencestest E/Test: 1295614410392 SYNC 
05-25 01:11:44.667 16109-16109/darklord.preferencestest E/Test: 1295669350041 SYNC index99999
05-25 01:11:45.257 16109-16109/darklord.preferencestest E/Test: 1296262306521 ASYNC 
05-25 01:11:45.317 16109-16109/darklord.preferencestest E/Test: 1296317374397 ASYNC NULL
```

I am expecting apply() to be must faster the commit(), however the result turned out to be they are the same. They are both not suitable to run on ui thread. So why this happens?

EDIT:
The log should be

```
05-25 01:11:44.608 16109-16109/darklord.preferencestest E/Test: 1295614410392 SYNC 
05-25 01:11:44.667 16109-16109/darklord.preferencestest E/Test: 1295669350041 SYNC index99999
05-25 01:11:45.257 16109-16109/darklord.preferencestest E/Test: 1296262306521 ASYNC 
05-25 01:11:45.317 16109-16109/darklord.preferencestest E/Test: 1296317374397 ASYNC index249999
```

I am testing on emulator api 17.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you're reading back the values from the in-memory

`SharedPreference` which you created before.

According to the documentation,

> apply() commits its changes to the in-memory SharedPreferences
>   immediately but starts an asynchronous commit to disk

Therefore, the in-memory `SharedPreference` will be updated immediately.

Comment: I tried just insert one record then the difference is significant. commit() takes 20ms and apply() returns immediately. To my surprise, if the number of records is very large like 100000 in my case, most of the time is spent on written to in memory shared preferences. The time spent on io is negligible. I would expect no matter how large the data set is, writing to memory should be much faster than written to disk. It seems that's only true if the data set is small.